# Creating a responsive website with my layout

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

So I read a few other threads here for creating a responsive website. Unfortunately, I can't use the info given on them because I kinda have a unique layout to my website. The layout is split right in the middle where the left side is not scrollable, but the right side is. When the screen gets smaller, I want the left side to come on top and the right side (the scrollable side), to be at the bottom so the user can just scroll up and down like on a mobile device. Been finding different solutions to this, but non seem to work. 
Can anyone help me out?

Here is the code (note the split left and split right divs):

```
<body>
```

```
<div class="split-left">
    <div class="centered">
    <img src="file:///Users/Kavinda/Documents/Whammy/Web%20Development/Cover.png" class="cover">
    </img>
    </div>

    <header>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" class="menu">Menu</a>
                <div class="arrowup">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#aboutus">About Us</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#newsletter">Newsletter</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Press Kit</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                </li>
            </ul>


            <!-- Social Media Links -->

            <div id="socialmedia">

            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/whammychat/?ref=bookmarks" target="_blank"> <img src="file:///Users/Kavinda/Documents/Whammy/Web%20Development/Social%20Media%20Icons/FB.png" alt="Facebook"></a>

            <a href="https://twitter.com/whammychat" target="_blank"> <img src="file:///Users/Kavinda/Documents/Whammy/Web%20Development/Social%20Media%20Icons/Twitter.png" alt="Twitter"></a>

            <a href="https://www.instagram.com/whammychat/" target="_blank"> <img src="file:///Users/Kavinda/Documents/Whammy/Web%20Development/Social%20Media%20Icons/Instagram.png" alt="Instagram"></a>

            </div>

        </nav>          
    </header>
</div>

<!-- RIGHT -->

<div class="split-right">
    <div class="centered">
        <img src="file:///Users/Kavinda/Documents/Whammy/Web%20Development/New%20Logo%20-%20Social%20Media.png" class="logo"></img>
        <div class=catchphrase>
            <h1> 
                <span class="messenger"> Messenger </span> 
                <span class="x"> x </span> 
                <span class="gaming"> Gaming </span> 
            </h1>
        </div>
        <p class="soon"> Coming Soon <p>
        <img class="gif" src="https://whammychat.files.wordpress.com/2018/01/gif-6-website.gif" alt="Intro GIF
        "/>
```

**The css:**

```
header ul li {
font-family: backtoschool;
position: relative;
z-index: 1.5;
list-style: none;
}

header ul li a {
display: block;
text-decoration: none;
color: white;
}

.menu {
border-style: solid;
border-color: white;
border-radius: 15px;
border-width: 1px;
margin: 4% 0% 0% -2%;
padding: 1.5%;
width: 10%;
text-align: center;
}

/* .menu {
transition: 1s ease;
}

.menu:hover {
-webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
-ms-transform: scale(1.1);
transform: scale(1.1);
transition: 0.5s ease;
} */

header ul li ul {
display: none;
position: absolute;
background-color: black;
padding: 0%;
border-radius: 10px;
border-style: none;
margin: 0% 0% 0% -3.5%;
}

header ul li:hover ul {
display: block;
}

header ul li ul li {
width: 100px;
}

header ul li ul li a {
padding: 15%;
}

header ul li ul li a:hover {
background: #696969;
border-radius: 10px;
border-style: none;
}


/*Social Media Icons*/

#socialmedia img {
position: relative;
z-index: 1.5;
left: 71%;
width: 8%;
margin-top: -100px;
padding-bottom: 43px;
height: auto;
}

@keyframes bounce {
0%, 20%, 60%, 100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
}

40% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(20px);
    transform: translateY(20px);
}

80% {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(10px);
    transform: translateY(10px);
}
}

#socialmedia img:hover {
animation: bounce 1s;
}




.split-left {
position: fixed;
height: 100%;
width: 50%;
z-index: 1;
top: 0;
left: 0;
}

.split-right {
margin-left: 50%;
width: calc(100%-50%);
height: auto;
}
```

Comment: I would recommend looking into CSS Grid. It allows you to assign areas. So you can have media queries that completely rearrange the DIVs in your layout.
If you can provide the current css etc so we can see how it currently works, we will be able to more easily provide a working solution :)

Comment: ignore the fact that one part of your site is scrollable for now and search again, then you will find hundreds of solutions. Use one of these and then make the area scrollable, this doesn't have anything to do with arranging your columns.

Comment: @KeeghanMcGarry I added the CSS :)

Answer (score 0):

first of all if you are using classes like`split left` 
just write them as `<div class="split-left"></div>`and just add this css  for the

**left side**

```
.split-left
 {
   position:fixed;
   width:400px;
   top:0;
   left:0;
   height:100%;
 }
```

***for the right side, you can use this***

```
.split-right
{
   margin-left:400px;
   width: calc(100% - 400px);
   height:auto;
   margin-left:0px;
   width: calc(100% - 0px);
}
```

you can use height with according to you.
for mobile responsive you can use media query

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) 
{
.split-left{width:100%; height:auto; position:relative;}
.split-right{width:100%; position:relative;}`
}
```

Comment: Hi so the classes work perfectly however, the media query doesn't function.
I attached my CSS on the original post as well

Comment: Waiting on your reply :)

Comment: I have made the changes on the media query have u tired with the updated code?